# Keras custom loss function (elastic net)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I'm try to code Elastic-Net. It's look likes:

[image: elsticnet formula]

And I want to use this loss function into Keras:

```
def nn_weather_model():
    ip_weather = Input(shape = (30, 38, 5))
    x_weather = BatchNormalization(name='weather1')(ip_weather)
    x_weather = Flatten()(x_weather)
    Dense100_1 = Dense(100, activation='relu', name='weather2')(x_weather)
    Dense100_2 = Dense(100, activation='relu', name='weather3')(Dense100_1)
    Dense18 = Dense(18, activation='linear', name='weather5')(Dense100_2)
    model_weather = Model(inputs=[ip_weather], outputs=[Dense18])
    model = model_weather
    ip = ip_weather
    op = Dense18
    return model, ip, op
```

my loss function is:

```
def cost_function(y_true, y_pred):
        return ((K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))+L1+L2)
   return cost_function
```

It's mse+L1+L2

and L1 and L2 is

```
weight1=model.layers[3].get_weights()[0]
weight2=model.layers[4].get_weights()[0]
weight3=model.layers[5].get_weights()[0]
L1 = Calculate_L1(weight1,weight2,weight3)
L2 = Calculate_L2(weight1,weight2,weight3)
```

I use Calculate_L1 function to sum of the weight of dense1 & dense2 & dense3
and Calculate_L2 do it again.

When I train `RB_model.compile(loss = cost_function(),optimizer= 'RMSprop')` the L1 and L2 variable didn't update every batch. So I try to use callback when batch_begin while using:

```
class update_L1L2weight(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(update_L1L2weight, self).__init__()
    def on_batch_begin(self,batch,logs=None):
        weight1=model.layers[3].get_weights()[0]
        weight2=model.layers[4].get_weights()[0]
        weight3=model.layers[5].get_weights()[0]
        L1 = Calculate_L1(weight1,weight2,weight3)
        L2 = Calculate_L2(weight1,weight2,weight3)
```

How could I use callback in the batch_begin calculate L1 and L2 done, 
and pass L1,L2 variable into loss funtion?

Comment: Why don't you directly use a weight regularizer on the layers?

Comment: hi, I had find keras had layer's L1 and L2, but I think it not same with the formula.      
The formula present the cost function is MSE+L1+L2 , but keras layer' L1 and L2 is just for layer , and every layer had single L1,L2 , I'm not sure this way is same with cost function+L1+L2, any helpful information ?

Comment: If you set the regularizers on layers, then they will be added to whatever loss you specify.

Comment: thanks for your comments , it there way to find the how keras calculate when layer used L1,L2 ? cheers.

Comment: I find formula in here, if anybody want to see , 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use built-in weight [regularization in Keras](https://keras.io/regularizers/) for each layer. To do that you can use `kernel_regularizer` parameter of the layer and specify a regularizer for that. For example:

```
from keras import regularizers

model.add(Dense(..., kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
```

Those regularizations would create a loss tensor which would be added to the loss function, as implemented in [Keras source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c10d24959b0ad615a21e671b180a1b2466d77a2b/keras/engine/training.py#L360-L363):

```
# Add regularization penalties
# and other layer-specific losses.
for loss_tensor in self.losses:
    total_loss += loss_tensor
```