# Constrained optimization using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, scikit-learn

I am trying to perform an optimization using Stochastic Gradient Descent to minimize the score of a model.

I tried to use scipy.minimize but I was quiet unhappy with how it could decide to overpass the bounds condition, and I decided to try to use TensorFlow

However, I do not manage to run the optimization. I am stuck because of tf.Variable. I define my variables but then, when I want to inject them in a sklearn model, it shows me an error message that you can see just after the code.

Here is the code:
'

```
initializer1 = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=0., maxval=1.)
initializer2 = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=0., maxval=100.)

def obj_fun(var):
    en=ElasticNet(**var)
    output=cross_val_score(en,x_train,y_train,scoring=make_scorer(mean_absolute_percentage_error,greater_is_better=False)).mean()
    return output

alpha=tf.Variable(initial_value=initializer2(shape=(1, )),
              dtype=tf.float32,
              constraint=lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, 0, 100),
              trainable=True
             )
l1_ratio=tf.Variable(initial_value=initializer1(shape=(1, )),
                 dtype=tf.float32,
                 constraint=lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, 0, 1),
                 trainable=True
                )

lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=1e-2,
                                                      decay_steps=10000,
                                                      decay_rate=0.9)

var={'alpha':alpha.value().numpy(),'l1_ratio':l1_ratio.value().numpy()}


losses = tfp.math.minimize(loss_fn=obj_fun(var),
                       optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule), #early stop
                       num_steps=10000
                      )'
```

The error message

```
    C:\Users\valentf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning: 
5 fits failed out of a total of 5.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valentf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 680, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\valentf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_coordinate_descent.py", line 925, in fit
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: l1_ratio must be between 0 and 1; got l1_ratio=[0.7919996]

  warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2256/3293299104.py in <module>
     25 
     26 
---> 27 losses = tfp.math.minimize(loss_fn=obj_fun(var),
     28                            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule), #early stop
     29                            num_steps=10000

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\math\minimize.py in minimize(loss_fn, num_steps, optimizer, convergence_criterion, batch_convergence_reduce_fn, trainable_variables, trace_fn, return_full_length_trace, jit_compile, seed, name)
    604 
    605   """
--> 606   _, traced_values = _minimize_common(
    607       num_steps=num_steps,
    608       optimizer_step_fn=_make_stateful_optimizer_step_fn(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\math\minimize.py in _minimize_common(num_steps, optimizer_step_fn, initial_parameters, initial_optimizer_state, convergence_criterion, batch_convergence_reduce_fn, trace_fn, return_full_length_trace, jit_compile, seed, name)
    151      initial_grads,
    152      initial_parameters,
--> 153      initial_optimizer_state) = optimizer_step_fn(
    154          parameters=initial_parameters,
    155          optimizer_state=initial_optimizer_state,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\math\minimize.py in optimizer_step(***failed resolving arguments***)
    423         loss = loss_fn(seed=seed)
    424       except TypeError:
--> 425         loss = loss_fn()
    426     watched_variables = tape.watched_variables()
    427     grads = tape.gradient(loss, watched_variables)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Does any one already have experience with tensorflow optimization and know how this code could work ? I really want to make it work !

Comment: You can't interface sklearn and tensorflow/keras like that. However, you can get by in tensorflow using a Dense layer with  kernel_regularizer. This link [keras-custom-loss-function-elastic-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304185/keras-custom-loss-function-elastic-net) may help you, even if it is not straightforward because you will have to deal with the L1/L2 losses.

Comment: Sorry, you don't have to worry about the additional loss in case of predefined kernel_regularizer such as L1 and L2